# Specialize template template parameter with a non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, clang++

I'm trying to have partial specialization of a class template, where one template parameter is a template template parameter containing a single non-type parameter.  For example:

```
template <
    class T, 
    template <class Result, Result> class BinaryOperation
>
struct Foo;

template <
    template <class Result, Result> class BinaryOperation
>
struct Foo<
    int,
    BinaryOperation
>
{ };
```

This code compiles fine using GCC-4.9.2.

However, using Clang-4.0, I get a cryptic error message:

```
$ clang++-4.0 test.cpp -o test -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ 
test.cpp:18:3: error: template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template
      parameter
                BinaryOperation
                ^
test.cpp:14:33: note: template non-type parameter has a different type 'Result' in template argument
                template <class Result, Result> class BinaryOperation
                                              ^
test.cpp:9:33: note: previous non-type template parameter with type 'Result' is here
                template <class Result, Result> class BinaryOperation
```

I've been Googling around for this error message, but it's very unclear to me.  It seems to be saying that `Result` is somehow considered a different type when it appears as a template parameter versus when it appears as one of the arguments to the specialization list.

It works on GCC-4.9.2, so I don't know if this is a problem with Clang 4, or if GCC-4.9.2 is allowing something that it shouldn't.

So why does Clang-4 report this compiler error?

Comment: No complaints from gcc 8.3, either, and I do not see anything that's obviously amiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug reported on Clang bugzilla for this titled: [Alias template produces seemingly bogus "template template argument has different template parameters" error](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37157)

This bug can be resolved in Clang 4 with the compiler option `-frelaxed-template-template-args`.

See [demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/Eok_nz).

This has been fixed in later versions of Clang (from 5.0.0 onwards).